# Sql join solution is possible for below case?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Can we solve below case with joins, I have solved with window functions

Relation: In the tables below, each order in the Orders table, is associated with a given Customer through the cust_id foreign key column that references the ID column in the Customer table.

Question: Find the largest order amount for each salesperson and the associated order number, along with the customer to whom that order belongs and sales person name.

```
Create Table Salesperson 
(
    ID          int,
    name        varchar(100),
    age         float,  
    salary      money
);

Create Table Orders
(
    Number          int,
    order_date      datetime,
    cust_id         int,    
    salesperson_id  int,
    Amount          money
);

Create Table Customer
(
    ID              int,
    name            varchar(100),
    city            varchar(100),   
    IndustryType    varchar(100)
);

insert into Salesperson  values 
( 1,'Rohit',25,50000),
( 2,'Pramod',25,50000),
( 3,'Atul',25,50000);

insert into Orders values 
( 1,getdate(),101,1,50000),
( 2,getdate(),101,1,500000),
( 3,getdate(),102,1,10000),
( 4,getdate(),101,2,5000),
( 5,getdate(),102,2,700000),
( 6,getdate(),102,2,10000);

insert into Customer values 
( 101,'Altu','bhopal','IT'),
( 102,'bltu','bhopal','ITES'),
( 103,'cltu','bhopal','NW');
```

Solution on with window function:

```
with CTE_MaxAmount
as
(
    select max(amount) over (partition by salesperson_id ) as amount,
           dense_rank() over (partition by salesperson_id order by amount) as rowid,
           cust_id,
           salesperson_id,number 
    from   Orders with(nolock)
)
select ct.amount, 
       ct.cust_id,
       c.name as customername,
       s.name as salesman,
       ct.salesperson_id,
       number as OrderNumbner 
from   Customer c 
join   CTE_MaxAmount ct 
on     (c.id = ct.cust_id)
join   Salesperson s 
on     (s.id = ct.salesperson_id)
where  rowid = 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm breaking with my personal policy not to answer homework questions because the question is an opportunity to show how easily English is translated into SQL.  The question is phrased exactly as the query can be built up.

> find the largest order amount for each salesperson

```
select max(Amount) as Amount, salesperson_id from Orders group by salesperson_id
```

> and the associated order number

```
select o.Number, M.salesperson_id, M.Amount
from Orders as o join (
    select max(Amount) as amount, salesperson_id
    from Orders group by salesperson_id
) as M
on   o.salesperson_id = M.salesperson_id
and o.Amount = M.Amount
```

> along with the customer

```
select c.name, o.Number, M.salesperson_id, M.Amount
from Orders as o join (
    select max(Amount) as amount, salesperson_id
    from Orders group by salesperson_id
) as M
on   o.salesperson_id = M.salesperson_id
and o.Amount = M.Amount
join Customer as c
on o.cust_id = c.ID
```

> and sales person name

```
select s.name as 'salesperson',
c.name as 'customer',
o.Number, M.salesperson_id, M.Amount
from Orders as o join (
    select max(Amount) as amount, salesperson_id
    from Orders group by salesperson_id
) as M
on   o.salesperson_id = M.salesperson_id
and o.Amount = M.Amount
join Customer as c
on o.cust_id = c.ID
join Salesperson as s
on o.salesperson_id = s.ID
```